# Can only see x86 in Wix Build configuration

Tags: wix, installation

I want to make a 64 bit installer for an office add-in. When I go into configurations of the installer I can only see x86 in the dropdown. Any ideas why x64 is not showing up?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Configuration Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328.aspx) in Visual Studio to configure a x64 platform.